# Chef - Recipe package fails to find candidate version

Tags: jenkins, package, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am installing and configuring a very basic Jenkins installation using Chef. When i attempt to run the following recipe:

```
include_recipe "apt::default"

apt_repository "jenkins" do
  uri "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian"
  key "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org"
  components ["binary/"]
  action :add
end

package "jenkins" do
  version '2.62'
end


service "jenkins" do
  supports [:stop, :start, :restart]
  action [:start, :enable]
end
```

I receive the following errors (displayed in the terminal):

```
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
192.168.9.207 Running handlers complete
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
192.168.9.207 Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated in 20 seconds
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 2b59b80e-b787-4e93-805b-837b4d3264fb)
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] ERROR: apt_package[jenkins] (jenkins-installation::default line 21) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for jenkins
192.168.9.207 [2017-05-25T10:50:58-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

The error explains that there is no candidate version available for Jenkins. After the run fails, if I run sudo apt-get update on the managed node I receive the following error:

```
Err http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org trusty/binary/ amd64 Packages                    
  404  Not Found
Err http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org trusty/binary/ i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org trusty/binary/ Translation-en_US       
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org trusty/binary/ Translation-en
Fetched 5,976 kB in 3s (1,528 kB/s)             
W: Failed to fetch http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/dists/trusty/binary//binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/dists/trusty/binary//binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am fairly new to Chef. This error appears to be related to retrieving a Jenkins package, however I am not sure how to remedy this error. Please let me know if additional information is required to troubleshoot this issue.

Thank you to everybody in advance for any guidance you are able to provide. I have searched through the Chef documentation but haven't seen much aside from specifying the package version: https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html.

Comment: the `version` argument for the `package` resource will btw. not work with apt. You have to use explicit apt pinning (which is a bit a PITA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `distribution 'binary/'` instead of `components 'binary/'`. This will fix the 404s that you get because of `trusty/binary/`.

At least, this is what I see from the ["official" Jenkins cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/7c2d0d36af8ecc4eed387e1473148ce5e428e038/recipes/_master_package.rb#L30), which I btw. suggest to use.

EDIT: So the result would be:

```rb
apt_repository "jenkins" do
  uri "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian"
  key "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org"
  distribution "binary/"
end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did modify components to distribution, however upon initiating a chef-client run which includes the recipe in the run list I receive the following error: [2017-05-25T11:59:42-04:00] ERROR: Property distribution must be one of: String, nil, false!  You passed ["binary/"]. Is there a property other than binary I should be passing in this case?

Comment: No, you passed a list, not a string. Will edit my question.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction @StephenKing